# Write array formulas

Tags: ms-office, office-js

To copy single formulas from an area to another, we could use directly `rangeTarget.formulas = rangeSource.formulas` once `rangeSource.formulas` is loaded. However, this method does not seem to apply to array formulas.

For example, `A1:A8` contains an array formula `{=B1:B8+10}`, and the following code attempts to copy this array formula to `C1:C8`:

```
function test () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var r0 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:A8");
        r0.load(["formulas"]);
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            var r1 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("C1:C8");
            r1.formulas = r0.formulas;
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the result (Excel Online and Excel for Windows):

[image]

So does anyone know what's the correct way to copy an array formula?

Additionally, I don't know how to enter an array formula manually in Excel Online, the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` does not seem to work (on Mac keyboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array Formulas are not currently supported by the Office.js Excel APIs. However, please feel free to suggest / vote for it on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, Developer on Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: OK... And, is it possible to manually enter an array formula in Excel Online?

Comment: Not sure... Though I imagine that if you upload a workbook that does have one, it will probably treat it correctly.